# Print all possible routes between C to D in Graph only visiting once

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, nodes, graph-theory

Working on a problem for graph traversal given a start and end.
Example if given edge routes:
("A","B")
("A","C")
("A","D")
("B","C")
("B","D")

Answer would be:
(C,B,D)
(C,A,D)
(C,A,B,D)
(C,B,A,D)

I am implementing this with two methods addRoute and printRoutes that take a start and des(the source and destination).

I created addRoute to add them, but having trouble trying to find a good solution to print all unique routes.

Solution so far is to convert it to an adjacency list and to run DFS or BFS on it. I need some help creating the BFS/DFS algoritum for this.

```
public class Graph{
    List<List<String>> edges= new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Set<String>> adjList= new HashMap<>();

     void addRoutes(String start, String des) {
         List<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<>();
         temp1.add(start);
         temp1.add(des);
        edges.add(temp1);
        adjList.putIfAbsent(start, new HashSet<>());
        adjList.putIfAbsent(des, new HashSet<>());
        adjList.get(start).add(des);
        adjList.get(des).add(start);
    }
        void printRoutes(String start, String des) {
     Set<String> visited = new HashSet<>();
     // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it

     // Create a queue for BFS
     Queue<List<String> > queue = new LinkedList<>();
     // Path vector to store the current path
     List<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
     path.add(start);
     queue.offer(path);

     while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
         path = queue.poll();
         String last = path.get(path.size() -1);
         if (last == des) {
             int size = path.size();
             for(String v : path) {
                 System.out.print(v + " ");
             }
         }
         Set<String> lastNode = adjList.get(last);
         for (String neig : adjList.get(start)) {
             if (!visited.contains(neig)) {
                 List<String> newpath = new ArrayList(path);
                 visited.add(start);
                 queue.offer(newpath);
             }

         }
     }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph g = new Graph();
        g.addRoutes("A","B");
        g.addRoutes("A","C");
        g.addRoutes("A","D");
        g.addRoutes("B","C");
        g.addRoutes("B","D");
        System.out.println(g.edges);
        System.out.println(g.adjList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Running BFS should work; what issue are you facing?

Comment: I need some help creating the BFS/DFS algoritum for this.

Comment: Check Algorithms book by Robert Sedgewick. It has examples and explanation of Bfs and Dfs, from that get some inspiration and make your own. In your code you are creating data structure but have not trying solving the main problem

Comment: I did try printRoutes method using DFS but was not able to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using BFS (or DFS) is right idea for getting all simple paths between vertices.

You just need to modify these algorithms a bit:  BFS uses global `visited` marks data. Instead make `visited` data structure local to every branch - as parameter of recursive function in case of recursive implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did try usinga visited set but could not get it to work. Edited printRoutes with my code but its not working correctly.

Comment: [Simple Python example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1232618/291659)

Comment: can that be translated to java please?